# Perl: Reading from a database table line by line

Tags: perl, dbi

Is there someway to read from a database table line by line using the DBI module? The table is huge and I keep running out of memory if I try to do a select. I'm working with an oracle database

Comment: Um ... http://www.google.com/search?q=%2BDBI+%2Bcursor+%2Boracle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many databases support a "LIMIT" clause in the SQL.  Or you could SELECT given a range of primary keys with a WHERE clause to constrain how much data you get back per query.

Comment: Thanks. I got the rowid's first and saved it to file. Then read sequentially using the rowid.

Answer (score 2):

The problems lies in your query. You must restrain your results set.

As mentioned by DavidO, LIMIT is a solution.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT whatever FROM wherever LIMIT 50");
$sth->execute;
my $row;
while (my @data = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
print "my $row(@row)";
sleep(1);
}
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

Comment: I'm using oracle. I believe this is for mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If you don't want to get *all* the results at once, get them with a DBI function that doesn't have *all* in its name.  e.g.,

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT whatever FROM wherever");
$sth->execute;
while (my @data = $sth->fetchrow_array) {  # returns just one row
  # do stuff with @data
}
```